# Array From Another Class

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a method: "*public boolean hasModelName(String modelName)*". I'm trying to call a method getModelName() from another class and array but can't figure out how to do it. I posted the class below. When I try and compile it says, "*cannot find symbol - method getModelName()*". That is in the Lamborghini class and  array. The method is a foreach loop and you can see the LamborghiniCarLot class there. That has the  array. This class doesn't. The last method on the bottom is where I'm stuck*(String hasModelName = lambo.getModelName();*). With how I have it, can I use getModelName() somehow or do I have to do this another way?

```
public class LamborghiniDealershipGroup
{

    private String dealershipGroupName; //e.g. Taylor's Auto Group


    private ArrayList<LamborghiniCarLot> carLots; //A collection of LamborghiniCarLots

/**
 * Creates carLots ArrayList object
 * Does NOT add any LamborghiniCarLot objects to carLots ArrayList
 */

public LamborghiniDealershipGroup()
{
    carLots = new ArrayList<LamborghiniCarLot>();

}

/**
 * Creates carLots ArrayList object
 * Creates the following objects
 */

public LamborghiniDealershipGroup(String dealershipGroupName)
{
    carLots = new ArrayList<LamborghiniCarLot>();

    //Create the first car lot
    LamborghiniCarLot carlot1 = new LamborghiniCarLot();

    carlot1.setLotName("Jason's vintage lambos.");
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1965, "350GT", 365.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1966, "400GT 2+2", 366.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1967, "MIURA", 367.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1968, "espada", 368.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1969, "islero", 369.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1970, "jarama", 370.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1971, "urraco", 371.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1971, "urraco", 371.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1973, "countache", 373.3, false)); 
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1974, "silhouette", 374.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1975, "jalpa", 375.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1976, "silhouette", 476.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1977, "silhouette", 377.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1978, "countache", 478.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1978, "countache", 578.3, false));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1978, "countache", 378.3, true));
    carlot1.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(1979, "silhouette", 479.3, false));

    //Create the second car lot
    LamborghiniCarLot carlot2 = new LamborghiniCarLot();

    carlot2.setLotName("Taylor's brand new lambos.");

    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2006, "gallardo", 506.3, true));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2007, "gallardo", 507.3, true));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2008, "reventon", 308.3, false));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2008, "reventon", 508.3, true));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2009, "gallardo", 409.3, true));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2010, "murcielago", 310.3, false));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2011, "aventador", 411.3, false));
    carlot2.addLamborghini(new Lamborghini(2012, "sesto elemento", 512.3, true));

    //Add them to the arraylist
    carLots.add(carlot1);
    carLots.add(carlot2);

}

/**
 * accessor method to get car lots
 * @return car lots
 */ 

public ArrayList<LamborghiniCarLot> getCarLots()
{
    return carLots;

}   

/**
 * mutator method to set car lots
 * @param car lots
 */ 

public void setCarLots(ArrayList<LamborghiniCarLot> setCarLots)
{
    this.carLots = carLots;

}

/**
 * accessor method that returns dealership group name
 * @return dealership group name
 */

public String getDealershipGroupName()
{
    return dealershipGroupName; 

}

/**
 * mutator method that sets dealership group name
 * @param - dealershipGroupName
 */

public void setDealershipGroupName(String dealershipGroupName)
{
    this.dealershipGroupName = dealershipGroupName;
}

/**
 * Adds the carLot provided to the carLots ArrayList
 * Does not add to the carLots ArrayList if carLot is null
 */

public void addCarLot(LamborghiniCarLot carLot)
{
    if(carLot != null)
    {
        carLots.add(carLot);

    } 

}

/**
 * Using a foreach loop, gets the total inventory of car lots
 * Returns 0 if carLots ArrayList is null
 */

public int getTotalInventoryCount()
{
    int totalIC = 0;
    int cars = 0;

    for(LamborghiniCarLot l : carLots){
        if(l.getInventory().equals(getCarLots())){
            l.getInventory().size();
            cars++;
        }
    }
    return cars;

}

/**
 * Returns true if the model name exists in ANY of the car lots
 * Returns false if the model name cannot be found, or if the carLots ArrayList is null
 * Uses a case-insensitive search(e.g. I can pass in "diablo", or "DIABLo", and still
 * find the same, correct model name)
 */

public boolean hasModelName(String modelName)
{

    boolean found = false;
    for(LamborghiniCarLot lambo : carLots)
    {

        String hasModelName = lambo.getModelName();
        if(hasModelName.equalsIgnoreCase(modelName)) 
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
        return found;

}
```

Comment: Well where's the definition of `getModelName()`?

Comment: In Lamborghini class: public String getModelName().....return modelName;

Comment: But you're not calling `getModelName()` on a `Lamborghini`. You're calling it on `lambo`, which is a `LamborghiniCarLot`.

Comment: That's right because its the only way I've found. This class has one array: LamborghiniCarLot. If I switched LamborghiniCarLot with Lamborghini in the loop, BlueJ says: "incompatible types: LamborghiniCarLot cannot be converted to Lamborghini".

Answer (score 0):

Think this through from the start. You have a `LamborghiniDealershipGroup`. This group has several `LamborghiniCarLot` objects in its `carLots` array. Each `LamborghiniCarLot` object has some number of `Lamboughini` objects in some array. You want to get at those `Lamboughini` objects' model names. So first iterate the group's car lots, and iterate through each car lot's cars.

```
public boolean hasModelName(String modelName)
{
    for(LamborghiniCarLot carLot : carLots)
    {
        for(Lamborghini lambo : carLot.getInventory()) //TODO: substitute in the right name
        {
            if(lambo.getModelName().equalsIgnoreCase(modelName)) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Here is what I have: "for(Lamborghini lambo : carLot.getInventory())" . It compiles but when I test the object, everything is still false. No more NPE though. That getInventory() method is from the LamborghiniCarLot class where this instance variable is: private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory;

Comment: That warrants a new question, with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Link it here and I'll take a look at it for you. If this answer satisfies the question in the original post, please rate and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have defined `private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory;` in `LamborghiniCarLot` class, and a getter

```
public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getInventory() {
     return inventory;
}
```

Now, here is a solution for your issue:

```
public boolean hasModelName(String modelName) {
    for(LamborghiniCarLot carLot : carLots) {
        for(Lamborghini lambo : carLot.getInventory()) {
            if(lambo.getModelName().equalsIgnoreCase(modelName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, the method `public String getModelName()` must be defined in `Lamborghini` class.

Comment: @Dang: that's exactly what I came up with, thanks a bunch. Can compile but now I have to fix why it always returns false no matter if I put in something real like "espada" or a fake car name.